# Problems with changed number formats after re-opening excel 2007 files

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a strange problem in Excel 2007. In some files I used in the past, the number format of many cells is changed when I re-open the files. I.e. a cell with the number format "#,##0.00" is formated as a date and is displayed with a Chinese font after re-opening. Or the standard number format becomes "0.00 "EUR"" which I sometimes use as user defined format.

Any ideas for the reason or how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For reasons unknown, and apparently never corrected, the NORMAL style spontaneously changes to Date. Said to be more common in shared workbooks.

You need to change it in the Styles dialog.  Since I no longer have 2007, I cannot give you step-by-step.  You should be able to find it on the Styles tab, though.